# using year in date parameter c# crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I made a parameter in parameter field to sort my data with year, but then when i debug and run it, the list of year looks like this `2,013` instead of `2013`.  **Is it possible to change it?**

I put this code in selection formula>>record

```
{DataTable1.payment_date}
   IN Date( Year(DataDate), {?Date}, 1) 
   TO Date( DateAdd("m", 1,  Date( Year(DataDate), {?Date}, 1)) - 1 ) 
   AND Year({DataTable1.payment_date}) = {?Year}
```

to sort my data and display it with the month and year i want.

Comment: This is just a problem how you formatted the year-field in crystal report. Just specify that you want to display it as a simple number without decimal values and thousand seperators

Comment: i didnt make the list of year in crystal report, the one im talking about is that the one i made in parameter field, the year represents as the values of the parameter

Comment: Can you post your Formula Field code that is showing the 2,1013. The selection code should not matter.

Comment: i dont have a formula field code, the only code i made is this {DataTable1.payment_date}
   IN Date( Year(DataDate), {?Date}, 1) 
   TO Date( DateAdd("m", 1,  Date( Year(DataDate), {?Date}, 1)) - 1 ) 
   AND Year({DataTable1.payment_date}) = {?Year}

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have declared `?Date` as `Number` or `String` that is the reason you are facing this issue, I would suggest to declare its datatype as Date and try.

Comment: when i change it to Date, i cant put values.